# How do i select Tables name and Rows count and CHECKSUM_AGG for all tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I can't figure out how to select TalbeName,Rows Count,Table Hash  for all tables 
it is easy to select Rows count for all tables like this

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
```

But how to select `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) in addition,`

to get

```
TALBENAME_____________ ROWS_________ CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: So you want the checksum for all columns in a table?

Comment: what i really want is to detect if any table in the database is updated/insert into and to show the rows count, i want to select the table names, rows count, checksum for all columns, then do some changes in the database, and one more time select and exam the difference between the two selects, thanks

Comment: I think you have to build a dynamic SQL with which you can iterate through the tables for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 days of searching, I Found the solution using Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @table sysname
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlparam nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @HASH INT

DECLARE TABLE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT SC.NAME+'.'+TA.NAME FROM SYS.TABLES TA 
INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SC ON SC.SCHEMA_ID=TA.SCHEMA_ID ORDER BY 1 
OPEN TABLE_CURSOR 

WHILE 1=1 
BEGIN  
   FETCH TABLE_CURSOR INTO @TABLE
   IF @@FETCH_STATUS<>0
      BREAK     
   SET @sqlCommand = N'SELECT @CNT=COUNT(*),@HSH=CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) from '+@table
   SET @sqlparam=N'@CNT INT OUTPUT, @HSH INT OUTPUT'
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, @sqlparam,  @COUNT OUTPUT,  @HASH OUTPUT
   PRINT @TABLE+': '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@COUNT)+':'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@HASH)
END
CLOSE TABLE_CURSOR 
DEALLOCATE TABLE_CURSOR
```